# Excel VBA - Nested IF applying colours to graphs

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the following code?

It is working most of the time, however sometimes it fails to apply proper colour. For example if the % change from 97% to 100% in cell D112, it will not apply the green colour, but in some cases it will.

Basically based on a % value of a cell D112, I want to apply different colour to the bar chart.

```
If Range("D112") < 0.96 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 0, 51)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 51)

ElseIf Range("D112") >= 0.96 And Range("D112") <= 0.98 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

Else
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 153, 102)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 102)
End If
```

Comment: You don't have a test for values >.98 so the color will be undefined. 
 Add one more condition to handle if > .98 and specify a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**: you can replace you multiple `If`s and `Else` with `Select Case`, it will clean and shorten you code by a lot.

**Second**: there's no need to select the chart and the point in each of these conditions, you are repeating the same procedures for all scenarios, you can do that before the `If`s section (or `Select Case`).

**Third**: it's better to avoid using `Select`, `Activate` and `Selection`, instead fully qualify all your Chart, Series and Point objects.

More explanation in the code below;

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorGraphs()

Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series
Dim SerPoint As Point

' set the ChartObject
Set ChrtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18")

' set the Series
Set Ser = ChrtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

' set the series point
Set SerPoint = Ser.Points(3)

' these setting are the same for all your scenarios
With SerPoint.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

Select Case Range("D112").Value
    Case Is < 0.96
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 0, 51)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 51)

    Case 0.96 To 0.98
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 0)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

    Case Else ' larger than 0.98
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 153, 102)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 102)

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to add colour to all the bar in the bar chart? For example, right now I have Oct and Nov bar, tomorrow I will get Dec bar once i get the new data, can the macro apply colour to December bar automatically?